# ViM + CtrlP: Persist the cache between ViM sessions

Tags: vim, ctrlp

While ViM is running, CtrlP's cache file exists. However, when I quit ViM, CtrlP's cache file is deleted. How can the cache file be persisted between sessions?

Comment: [Reading help](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L216) suggested to `let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit = 0`. Does it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you wish for your cache files to persist between sessions, you can

```
let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit = 0
```

See [help](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L216).